# Does Knopflerfish OSGi desktop require a connection to www.knopflerfish.org?

Tags: osgi, knopflerfish

I'm trying a tutorial for OSGi that uses the knopflerfish desktop.  Today, it hangs when I try to open a local .jar file to install it as a new bundle.  It spits out a message on the console
    [stderr] Error when connecting to 'http://www.knopflerfish.org/releases/3.1.0/repository.xml': java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect

and indeed, www.knopflerfish.org seems to be down today.  It there no way to use this tool without a connection to the mothership?

Answer (score 0):

You can still use the Knopflerfish Desktop. The missing connection should not keep you from using the desktop since you can also use it when you are working offline.

The Knopflerfish web site is/was down as mentioned in a blog post by Christer Larsson (see http://knopflerfish.blogspot.com/2011/03/knopflerfish-web-site-temporarily-down.html )